# I wish you had told me that you are/were my son. Which is the correct option?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> I wish you had told me that you are/were my son.
>
> Here you are! I wish you had told me that you are/were here.
>
> I wish I had been told that she is/was/were my sister.

Not sure about the sequence of tenses. Should it be "are" or "were"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to [direct speech](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/direct-and-indirect-speech/), which is exactly quoted, [reported speech](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/reported-speech.html) calls for a tense [backshift](https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017). That's because you're conveying what *was* said in the past, or in the case what the speaker wishes *was* said (or *had been said* in the pluperfect subjunctive) in the past, not what *is* true in the present, so you'd say, "I wish you had told me that you ***were*** my son."

Remember, the present veracity of the content of what was said or one wishes had been said is not what's being conveyed. What's being conveyed is what was said or one wishes had been said. Obviously, once a son, always a son, so saying "were" does not suggest that the listener is no longer the speaker's son but is merely reporting past speech the listener did not provide but the speaker wishes he had.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine,  I'd prefer "you are my son" since this is a fact that continues to the present, but backshifting is correct too.